# jQuery, check on empty input box

Tags: jquery

A very simple question:

If I do: `$(":input").css("background-color","#ffffff")`, the result is that all input fields get a white background.

Logic would say that `$(":input[value=]").css("background-color","#000000")`, would make the background colour black of input fields without a value, but that doesn't work (latest jQuery version). I've tried `[value='']` as well, but to no avail.

I can't believe .each to be the only solution. It has got to be simpler.

EDIT: The code is like this:

```
<form id="frm_Auth" action="javascript:;"> 
   User name: <input type="text" size="10" id="frm_Auth_Username"  value="" />
   Password: <input type="password" size="10" id="frm_Auth_Password" value="" /> 
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#frm_Auth").on("submit", function() 
 { 
   $(":input").css("background-color","#ffffff"); $(":input[value=]").css("background- color","#FFCECE"); 
});
```

Comment: "Lastest jQuery version" meaning 1.9, or 2?

Comment: Downloaded today, so that's got to be 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get this to work fine, but I haven't seen your html.  It's possible that your `input`s do not have `value` attributes at all, but you can check that with `:input:not([value])`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GUuQQ/

**EDIT:** if you want to check whether you should update the background any time the user changes the value, you can bind a check to `keyup`:

```
$(":input").on('keyup', function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is checking the `value` attribute.  This will not work for fields which were initially blank but someone typed into.

Comment: @JamesMontagne true, but that sort of depends on when he actually wants to check this.  Seems like it would be on page load since checking when a user entered something should be done via a `keydown` event or the like

Comment: Okay, I'm getting somewhere. As @ExplosionPills indicated, I did forget the value="" in the HTML. James Montagne also comes with an interesting point, since indeed I want to do the check with an initially blank field, but which was filled in by the user. It seems that my solution above only works if the value was initially set in the HTML.

Comment: @Remy in that case it would be better to check on the `keypress` event to check whether there is a value and change the color based on that

Comment: @ExplosionPills I could do it with .each and that did work, but I wanted a more elegant solution. I'm a bit puzzled why the $(":input[value=]") only works with the initial value set and not after the onsubmit event (after typing a new value).

Comment: @Remy because it's checking the `value` *attribute* rather than property (changed by the user).  No need to use `.each`, just bind like `$(":input").on('keypress'`

Comment: @ExplosionPills That makes, unfortunately :), sense. I've gone for the solution, but not with "keypress", but "keyup". I'm new here, so what to do now? You helped me out, but it wasn't really the answer.

Comment: @Remy I'll edit the answer to include the details we discussed; then you can upvote/accept